# SwiftUI - Move path of image file in Storage to Realtime database on Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have successfully added imgae file to Storage, but I don't know how can I move the path file image in Storage to Realtime Database so it can be displayed on UI.

In my Realtime database there is a field to contain the path of the image

I want to move path p4.jpg in Storage to image field in Realtime Database

func Update image to storage

```
func uploadImageToStorage(image: UIImage) {
    if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) {
        let storage = Storage.storage()
      storage.reference().child("").putData(imageData, metadata: nil) {( _, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("an error has occured - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("image uploaded successfully")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("Coldn't unwrap/case imgae to data")
    }
}
```

```
let imageURL = UIImage(named:"")
Button(action: {
        profileViewModel.uploadImageToFirebse(image: imgaeURL )
}) {
    Text("Upload Image")
}
```

Comment: The documentation has instructions for storing a value in the Realtime Database. Have you tried the strategies listed there? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: I read it, but I think it's not related to my problem

Comment: You've changed the tag and title back to including SwiftUI. SwiftUI is not related to this question at all -- SwiftUI is a framework for displaying UI elements on the screen. You haven't included any SwiftUI code. This is a "Swift" question.

Comment: You've read the documentation on adding information to Realtime Database but you don't think that it's related to your problem? Isn't your problem that you want to store the path in the Realtime Database? I must be misunderstanding the question in that case. Can you give more detail about what you're trying to do besides store the path?

Comment: i am working with swiftUI, not swift. I have updated the code above . please don't edit my question

Comment: What part of this question is specific to SwiftUI rather than Swift? As I understand it, you want to "Move path of image file in Storage to Realtime database on Firebase" (the title of your question) -- none of that is SwiftUI specific and will be done with Swift code. SwiftUI and Swift are not mutually exclusive, but the former is a UI framework and seems to have nothing to do with the crux of your issue. Tagging and titling the question with the right terms will help get it the attention from the community best suited to answer the question -- that's why I did the edit.

Comment: @jnpdx to display image in my project. I have to add an image file to Storage . Then will get the path from Storage to pass to the image field in the Realtime database . From the image field in the Realtime database I will display it to the UI

Comment: You already had the same question yesterday.  Moving the path of an image file from Firebase Storage to Firebase Realtime Database?  Your question didn't make sense yesterday.  And it still does not today.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need two functions: upload the image to storage, then upload the url to database.

```
func uploadImageToStorage(image: UIImage) {
    if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) {
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let photoRef = storage.reference().child("avatar/filename.jpg")
        photoRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) {( _, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("an error has occured - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                photoRef.downloadURL { url, err in
                    if let url = url {
                        // call function to add this url to database
                    } else {
                        // you might want to delete the image from storage
                        print("could not get download url")
                    }
                }
                print("image uploaded successfully")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("Coldn't unwrap/case imgae to data")
    }
}
```